# SUMIFS function across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

For reference, please visit this [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mCzcjqgT9WRBdm5NHdF5AWCRyWchcshfS-WGl_iGqbE/edit?usp=sharing) which is a simplified example of my problem, which is to determine total sales in Blue and Green markets each month.

Each month, I receive a new sales report from accounting for all of our markets and I add the sheet to the main workbook. My team is in charge of assigning "colors" to the markets and tracking this. As it's privileged information, we can't have accounting auto-tag these in the data they send over.

One solution would be, for each new monthly report that comes in, tag each city with the color. However, we have hundreds of markets and this isn't very practical to go through each time.

I assume that a SUMIFS function would work here, but am unsure how to set it up when there are values spread across multiple sheets.

Comment: You want to have a sum in each of the month-tabs? Could you maybe put in the spreadsheet, the way you want to present the results and highlight them in green (or something)?

Comment: SUMIFS will not accept a 3D reference; could you add your SUMIF to each sheet as it comes in, and then SUM those cells (SUM will accept a 3D reference).

Comment: "You want to have a sum in each of the month-tabs?"  Yes.  I've added in yellow highlights what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function in B8 of February tab:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,Color!$A$2:$A$5,Color!$B$2:$B$5,'Sales February'!A8)>0,$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

`COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,Color!$A$2:$A$5,Color!$B$2:$B$5,'Sales February'!A8)>0` gets an array of the countries that belong to the colour specified in A8 of the current tab (Would that be possible to put only `Green` and remove `February Sales` from that cell?).

If the country belongs to the particular colour, then return the array of corresponding values in column `$B$2:$B$5`.

Lastly, sum this array.

Note:

1. You need to array enter this formula in Excel (by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in the formula).
2. In Google Spreadsheets, you array enter a formula by wrapping the formula around `=ArrayFormula()`, meaning you use:

   ```
   =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$5,Color!$A$2:$A$5,Color!$B$2:$B$5,'Sales February'!A8)>0,$B$2:$B$5,0)))
   ```

[image]

Comment: Just tried this in Google Spreadsheets and it didn't seem to work. Perhaps this doesn't function in Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: @user2705241 Yea, I just saw that too. I guess it doesn't work with GoogleSpreadsheets :( But it works in Excel for sure.

Comment: I think it doesn't work on GS because COUNTIFS doesn't support array values yet, and it's also a recently added feature in GS.

Answer (score 2):

In **Excel** you can use this "array formula"

`=SUM(SUMIF(A$2:A$5,IF(Color!B$2:B$5=A8,Color!A$2:A$5),B$2:B$5))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The same formula works in **google docs** if wrapped in `arrayformula`, i.e.

`=arrayformula(SUM(SUMIF(A$2:A$5,IF(Color!B$2:B$5=A8,Color!A$2:A$5),B$2:B$5)))`

or you can use `FILTER` as `user3465711` suggests, i.e.

`=SUM(filter(B$2:B$5,isnumber(match(A$2:A$5,IF(Color!B$2:B$5=A8,Color!A$2:A$5),0))))`